# Check multiple Checkboxes to filter table rows matching each input label text

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter

In the snippet below, having one checkbox checked at a time works fine but checking multiple checkboxes doesn't work as desired. I'm guessing that when I check multiple checkboxes, for example `White` and `Orange`, the function is looking for `WhiteOrange` in the column cells, obviously leading to no results. How do I check for each label text one by one to get all matching results?

Also, how can I check for the initial state of the checkboxes before the change function so that only the results for `White` are shown when loading the page? I've tried running the filter function within the for loop before the change function, but it didn't work at all.

Thank you for your help; it is greatly appreciated!

```js
$(function() {
  const focusInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input.focusbox");
  const focusColumns4 = document.querySelectorAll("table#colors tbody tr td.table-cell:nth-child(4)");
  for (const focusInput of focusInputs) {
    $(focusInput).on('change', function() {
      if (!$(focusInput).is(":checked")) {
        $(focusColumns4).parent('tr').show();
      } else if ($(focusInput).is(":checked")) {
        $(focusColumns4).filter(function() {
          return $(this).text() !== $(focusInput).parent().text();
        }).parent('tr').hide();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 10px;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table#colors {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

table#colors tbody tr td.entry2 {
  width: 200px;
}

.cf-circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
  -webkit-transition: border-radius 1s, width 1s, height 1s;
  transition: border-radius 1s, width 1s, height 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><label class="focusbox-label"><input class="focusbox" type="checkbox" checked />White</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="focusbox-label"><input class="focusbox" type="checkbox" />Red</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="focusbox-label"><input class="focusbox" type="checkbox" />Orange</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<table id="colors">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="head-row">
      <th class="table-cell cYellow c1 entry1">Color</th>
      <th class="table-cell cYellow c1 entry2">Name</th>
      <th class="table-cell cYellow c1 entry3">HTML Color Code</th>
      <th class="table-cell cYellow c1 entry4">Shade Group</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">White</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#FFFFFF</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">White</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #F7E7CE;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">Champagne</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#F7E7CE</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">White</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #ED2839;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">Red (Pantone)</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#ED2839</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">Red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #ED1B24;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">Red (CMYK) (pigment red)</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#ED1B24</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">Red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #FF8200;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">UT orange</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#FF8200</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">Orange</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #FF8000;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">Orange (wheel)</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#FF8000</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">Orange</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a rather odd mix of jQuery and native JS. The use of `focusColumns4` also assumes that it is relevant to the colour of the checked box, when in fact it contains all the rows regardless of position in the DOM, or relation to the checkbox which triggered the `change` event.

What you're attempting to do can be achieved much more simply by setting the `value` of the checkboxes as the colour value to find within the DOM. Then you can build an array of the checked values and use that to hide/show the `tr` as necessary.

```js
$(function() {
  let $focusInput = $('input.focusbox');
  let $focusRows = $('table#colors tbody tr');
  
  let setRowStates = () => {
    $focusRows.hide();
    let values = $focusInput.filter(':checked').map((i, el) => el.value).get();   
    values.forEach(colour => $focusRows.filter(`:has(.entry4:contains('${colour}'))`).show());
  };
  
  $focusInput.on('change', setRowStates).trigger('change'); 
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 10px;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table#colors {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

table#colors tbody tr td.entry2 {
  width: 200px;
}

.cf-circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
  -webkit-transition: border-radius 1s, width 1s, height 1s;
  transition: border-radius 1s, width 1s, height 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><label class="focusbox-label"><input class="focusbox" type="checkbox" value="White" checked />White</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="focusbox-label"><input class="focusbox" type="checkbox" value="Red" />Red</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="focusbox-label"><input class="focusbox" type="checkbox" value="Orange" />Orange</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<table id="colors">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="head-row">
      <th class="table-cell cYellow c1 entry1">Color</th>
      <th class="table-cell cYellow c1 entry2">Name</th>
      <th class="table-cell cYellow c1 entry3">HTML Color Code</th>
      <th class="table-cell cYellow c1 entry4">Shade Group</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">White</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#FFFFFF</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">White</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #F7E7CE;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">Champagne</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#F7E7CE</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">White</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #ED2839;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">Red (Pantone)</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#ED2839</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">Red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #ED1B24;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">Red (CMYK) (pigment red)</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#ED1B24</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">Red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #FF8200;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">UT orange</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#FF8200</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">Orange</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #FF8000;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">Orange (wheel)</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#FF8000</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">Orange</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey Rory, thank you for sharing your approach. You're right with everything you said, all mixed up and unnecessary stuff in my code. With your code, and since I have the classes ".entryX"... there's no need at all to put the column in a variable. I can already specify which column I want to use. This is going to help me a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note sure why the mix between `jQuery` and `javascript`, but try this way:

```
$(function() {
  const focusInputs = $("input.focusbox");

  focusInputs.change(function() {
    var checked = focusInputs.filter(function() {
      return $(this).is(":checked")
    })
    var colors = checked.map(function() {
      return $(this).parent().text()
    }).get()

    if (colors.length == 0) {
      $('#colors tr').show();
    } else {
      $('#colors tr').hide();
      $('#colors tr').filter(function() {
        return $.inArray($(this).find(".entry4").text(), colors) > -1
      }).show();
    }

  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  const focusInputs = $("input.focusbox");

  focusInputs.change(function() {
    var checked = focusInputs.filter(function() {
      return $(this).is(":checked")
    })
    var colors = checked.map(function() {
      return $(this).parent().text()
    }).get()

    if (colors.length == 0) {
      $('#colors tr').show();
    } else {
      $('#colors tr').hide();
      $('#colors tr').filter(function() {
        return $.inArray($(this).find(".entry4").text(), colors) > -1
      }).show();
    }

  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 10px;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table#colors {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

table#colors tbody tr td.entry2 {
  width: 200px;
}

.cf-circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
  -webkit-transition: border-radius 1s, width 1s, height 1s;
  transition: border-radius 1s, width 1s, height 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><label class="focusbox-label"><input class="focusbox" type="checkbox" checked />White</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="focusbox-label"><input class="focusbox" type="checkbox" />Red</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="focusbox-label"><input class="focusbox" type="checkbox" />Orange</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<table id="colors">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="head-row">
      <th class="table-cell cYellow c1 entry1">Color</th>
      <th class="table-cell cYellow c1 entry2">Name</th>
      <th class="table-cell cYellow c1 entry3">HTML Color Code</th>
      <th class="table-cell cYellow c1 entry4">Shade Group</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">White</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#FFFFFF</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">White</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #F7E7CE;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">Champagne</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#F7E7CE</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">White</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #ED2839;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">Red (Pantone)</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#ED2839</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">Red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #ED1B24;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">Red (CMYK) (pigment red)</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#ED1B24</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">Red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #FF8200;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">UT orange</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#FF8200</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">Orange</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="s1">
      <td class="table-cell entry1">
        <div class="color-field cf-default cf-circle" style="background-color: #FF8000;"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell entry2">Orange (wheel)</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry3">#FF8000</td>
      <td class="table-cell entry4">Orange</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! Now I'm going to have to figure out what you did here :)

Comment: Wow this is amazing, thank you so much! I was looking for a simple way to create filter checkboxes without the use of IDs, values, data attributes, etc. and this is sooo cool. Very handy when it comes to filtering tables based on simple yes/no entries or other simple entries. Thank you, Carsten.